# Wordpress get_option print

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello how can i print in php the function `get_option('item')`

For example like this, but doesn't works

```
<?php  include '_includes/items/item_1.php';?>
```

instead of `item_1` to put `get_option('item')`

Any ideea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code below.

```
include '_includes/items/'.get_option('item').'.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php  include '_includes/items/'.get_option('item');?>
```